# What is dependency Analysis and how is it done?

Tags: .net, dependency-analysis

I saw this in a job posting for an ASP.net developer.

"An understanding of basic software development practices such as ...and Dependency Analysis."

I read the wikipedia entry for Dependency Analysis and understand that it basically means one thing depends on the other so you can't reorder or parallelize them.

What does this mean in practice?  Is there a tool that is used to do a Dependency Analysis?  What should I know about it for an interview and in practice if I get the job?

Answer (score 2):

When you say *Dependency Analysis*, the first tool that comes to mind is **NDepend**.

Here's a [great blog post by Scott Hanselman explaining how you can use it to analyze dependencies in your code](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExitingTheZoneOfPainStaticAnalysisWithNDepend.aspx).

You can use NDepend to create dependency graphs of your assemblies, use CQL (Code Query Language) to query for overly complicated classes and methods, and perform a number of other code analysis tasks.